# Copy as Curl in Chrome with POST says error 302 moved temporarily

Tags: php, curl, cygwin, scrape

I'm trying this out in shell with Curl before developing a full app. I need to obtain information from a public site where I input in two lines of info and it returns a one-line response in the browser. When I enter in the data in chrome, then under the chrome Developer Tools under Network it shows the POST command but with status as '302 moved temporarily.' When I run the 'copy as curl' data from Curl directly in the shell I receive "

This document you requested has moved temporarily.

It's now at a href="http.......
The URL its sending me to is the same except that its http instead of https. Is there any way I can use Curl for this? If not is there another tools I should be examining? I need to do this for dozens of similar sites. I can do it using human emulation commands but I'd prefer something much more stealthy that doesn't launch browser windows. 
[image: Chrome Data]

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasn't been answered yet, and I got here looking for a solution to my problem which had me stumped for a good while maybe this helps someone:

I was getting a '302 moved temporarily' and re-direct to GET on the same resource trying to POST a form which had been populated for editing. I had set an email input to required, and on editing set it to disabled in the html (as the user was not allowed to change it once stored).

The problem (after much studying of the headers, which seemed fairly identical) was solved by changing the html disabled attribute to readonly. The difference this made was that the email appeared in the POST string.

Now I'm no expert on http, but as I understand it, the server must somehow have known (perhaps cache?) that the html5 boolean attribute 'required' had been set when it didn't receive the field by POST. Perhaps someone who knows can explain because it still baffles me, but anyway there's my solution.

This was on a PHP script on IIS 8 (I know, but it's for work!) although the problem had nothing to do with PHP.